"Please use a modern browser" error when reading a REST API
I am trying to read a REST API from my Windows 10 laptop in VS Code in a python 3.11 script using the requests module. I finally got the API access to work after getting the latest .pem file but now when I print my response i get

alert('You are using Microsoft Internet Explorer as your web browser. ' +
'For security and performance reasons LogicManager is not supported on Internet Explorer. ' +
'Please use a modern web browser, such as Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge, to access LogicManager.');

my default browser is chrome and when I do
webbrowser.open('www.google.com')
it opens google up in a new chrome browser. I have gone to File>Preferences>Settings>Extensions>Live Preview and changed the browser from default to chrome, restart VS Code and run the code and i get the same error above.
I have also tried adding the user-agent to my header as follows

'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

which results in the same error.
If i create a python app in Visual Studio 2022 and copy and paste the code I get the same error.
Here is the code i am using
import requests

api_url = 'https://mycompany.logicmanager.com/v1/plans'

api_headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authentication' : 'Basic...' ,
    'api-key' : 'thekey',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

cert_file = 'localpathto.pem'

response = requests.get(url=api_url, headers=api_headers, verify=cert_file)

print(response.text)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Show your Python code as a [mcve].  Also read [ask].

Assuming you are using something like the requests module to access the API, try setting the User-Agent header to Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 (captured from Chrome).

I would just take all the headers from a similar request in Chrome, not just User-Agent and Content-Type.

What API is it, and can you anonymize api_url less than totally removing everything, e.g., can you only hide the domain but leave the path intact?

what is your default user agent? (e.g. when you go to https://whatmyuseragent.com on the browser without the error)

That's doesn't look like the right API. Are you following these instructions?

Many web servers look at more than just the User-Agent string to determine browser.  User agent is pretty useless these days anyway.  The server is likely expecting other headers.
Internet Explorer may just be the default if the server can't identify another browser specifically.
You can get all the headers that chrome passes.  Open a page in chrome from same domain as your REST target, then open dev tools -> network tab, refresh the page, find the document in the Name column, right click, copy -> copy as cURL.  This copies the curl command line to retrieve the pages with same headers as chrome used.  You'll get something like this:
curl 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'cookie: prov=123456' \
  -H 'origin: https://stackoverflow.com' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78552323/please-use-a-modern-browser-error-when-reading-a-rest-api' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Vax"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 blah blah blah' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest'

Add those headers to your api_headers dict and hopefully that does the trick.
It's also possible the server is using javascript detection.  That case is much more complicated.  Unlikely with REST but you never know how the server is (mis)configured.
